# Flutter firebase Reauthenticating a user not working

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working on a project which is based on firebase authentication (Email/password).
I need to add change password Options. when try to change credential showing error.

> Error "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."

I have tried with this code.

```
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  checkUser() {
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      print(auth.currentUser.email);
      changePass();
    } else {
      print("user not found");
    }
  }

  void changePass() async {
    print("clicked");
    EmailAuthCredential credential =
        EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: auth.currentUser.email, password: "Password@3221");

    await auth.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this one for reset password:

Future   resetpassword  (String email)

async

{

await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);

}

Comment: Thanks for reply ... but i want to change(update) existing password. i found reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) from official document but not working.

Comment: Its reset password and its working. can you please check this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#reauthenticating-a-user . i want to change password from app . where user input password and confirm password then click on chage password button.

Comment: Yaa this is also fine

Comment: can you please share your code? for update password (not reset)

Comment: Check my repository :https://github.com/amitsingh6391/Ecommerce-app-gitanjali-shop-